# Is it possible to experience powerful sensations, such as orgasm, without getting attached to it?

Tags: attachment, sexuality

I used orgasm as an example because it is usually the strongest sensation one can feel due to everything involved and all the chemistry released in the body.

Also, I would say that sexual activity and drinking are probably the two biggest challenges one has to overcome when following the 8 precepts for weeks or months.

So, can one feel it without attachments?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ostensibly, yes, I can't imagine why it wouldn't be technically possible for the body to trigger an orgasm without any kind of mental attachment. Of course, it may be that there is some necessary mental trigger involved, but I doubt that is true.

In the vinaya there are several cases that seem to suggest involuntary (physical) sexual arousal involving heat and motion; it seems reasonable to suggest that certain conditions could result in an involuntary ejaculation.

Simpler would be the case where one was intending to bring about an orgasm but then suddenly became mindful, only to find that it was too late (the point being that any attachment created would be in relation to the prior stimulation, not the orgasm itself).

Either way, it is important to clarify that *intentionally* bringing about an orgasm for the purpose of pleasure invariably leads to the cultivation of attachment.

Incidentally, IIRC, this is one of the issues that led to a split in the sangha, though I can't remember which one. One group thought that the fact that arahants can still experience orgasms meant that they were still not free from defilements; the other claimed that the orgasms were just physical processes with no mental counterpart.

Comment: What is IIRC ven. Sir?

Comment: @SumindaSirinathSalpitikorala If I Recall Correctly

Answer (score 6):

I have experienced ejaculation without it feeling "pleasant". When ejaculation does not feel pleasant, it feels more like semi-painful spasms. There is no attachment to this experience.

It is not that ejaculation has changed, or even that the experience changed. It is my *perspective* that has changed. If you look at pleasant sensation very very *very* carefully, then you will see it *as is* -- and it will loose it's luster.

The same with pain, if you look at it really close, you will see it as **information**. No pain, just information.

As Buddha taught, we must learn to see pleasant in non-pleasant and non-pleasant in pleasant. When we can arbitrarily control our evaluation of sensory experience, then we are free from it.

Comment: do you have a solution to avoiding "wet dreams" ?  

@Andrei Volkov

Answer (score 2):

Does the Buddhist breathe?
Does the Buddhist drink water?
Does the Buddhist eat food?
Does the Buddhist exercise?

If all of these needs can be met without attachment, why should sex be any different?

Sex can be entirely to meet one's biological urges, the way we eat and drink and exercise. I'm not saying it is easy to do so, but it seems to me that clearly the possibility exists.

Comment: It is possible to live decades without sexual contact. I can't say the same about oxygen, water, or food.

Comment: The experience of breathing and an orgasm are completely different, the chemicals it releases, the desire, the fantasy, we cannot compare it with breathing or drinking water I guess

Answer (score 2):

No. All healthy humans are biologically addicted to dopamine. "The brain includes several distinct [dopamine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dopamine) systems, one of which plays a major role in reward-motivated behavior. Most types of reward increase the level of dopamine in the brain, and a variety of addictive drugs increase dopamine neuronal activity."

Dopamine is the hormone that makes you feel good. If you can orgasm without it feeling good then, yes. You can never feel anything good without attachment. Humans are hardwired to like dope just as they do sugar and for the same reason; need. The need to procreate the species and the need to consume calories.

Answer (score 1):

To experience an orgasm you need some form of active arousal. If arousal is involved you are attached and goes against the precept.

If it is from other causes like bed wetting then it may be OK as long as you don't fantasise. If there is fantasy then again there is attachment.

Main thing to remember is sensation is involuntary sometimes but seeking sensations is not without attachments, and seeking sensations can be very subtle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing about Sexual activities....

We do not admire it like the western culture,But the eight fold path is not a hammer on your marriage life.You can still have sex but with her only.
And if you are single there is a set of guidelines established din Buddhism in finding the correct type for sex (Please refer a good source about Five precepts).

You can very well feel anything without getting attached to it,

**How do i know it?**

well arahants still felt the heat,coldness,soft touch of clothes,the comfort of a breezing wind,the beauty of a jungle.But still they had no disturbance from it they even admired the beauty of nature.

But in the examples you are presenting in your question we can't agree that it can be felt without the addiction to it. Basically the main reason for sex is the attachment that you have for it.

Sex is not a huge deal for a beginner but alcohol is an addiction with no virtual benefit,it is that simple and under n o circumstances can be justified as something a Buddhist would do. You can have some help from meditation to fight the urge to drink and some therapy or rehab would also help.that is something you will have to fight on your own.

Remember what Lord Buddha said

*This is an individual's fight against himself,in it he will need good friends,Knowledge of dharma and courage.But he must fight alone.*

Well we are here to help so start with one day without alcohol and let's see what happens from there.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Alagaddupama Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.022.than.html), it isn't possible:

> For a person to indulge in sensual pleasures without sensual passion, without sensual perception, without sensual thinking: That isn't possible.

The commentary makes it more precise:

> According to the Commentary, "indulge in sensual pleasures" here means indulging in sexual intercourse; the Sub-commentary adds that other acts expressing sexual desire — such as hugging and petting — should be included under this phrase as well.

Answer (score -1):

If all humans relize the ultimatos truth, "that all Beings be happy" all human race will go to an end passing less than 200 years. 
All humans produce dopamine but is a litle different to be addicted to This às a drug. Barry komisaruk can explain what are orgasms, non genital orgasms exist naturaly, just google it. While meditating you can gett orgasm and sleping. even if you have your reproductive organs totally inactive you should be atracted to the other may be.

Comment: This is a Buddhist community even though we welcome many perspectives your answer is a bit off topic, The question asks about attachment an how to be rid of it while sensations occur. Even-though you are right scientifically you are giving the wrong answer because it is off topic from the expected answers of the questioner. We understand you are new so next time read the question fully before answering it  Good luck and welcome to Stackexchange : )